# Is there a way to make inverse kinematics target anywhere on a path or surface instead of just a point?

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to make an animation of someone playing the piano (as automatically as possible using the MIDI). It would be nice if I could make them hit somewhere on the key instead of having to specify the exact spot. Obviously the middle finger will extend into the key further than the thumb, and it would be convenient to just give it a line segment where it could hit and have it figure out the easiest spot.

Comment: You can animate the targets along any path as much as you like. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: You misunderstand. I don't mean that I want the target to move along the path. I mean that I want it to just make sure it falls on some point in a path. As a simple example, maybe I want to set the x and y coordinates, but let the z coordinate be whatever results in the simplest kinematics.

Comment: I don't think that's possible without animation nodes.